# Zyxel Router micro_httpd 404 error when polling

Tags: html, node.js, http

this might be a very specific question, but I'm hoping to find someone who delt with the same thing in the past.

So I poll data from the web frontend of my router (192.168.1.1 or o2.box) with nodejs every minute. The sequence is as follows:

- Visit /index.html and extract Session Key with regex (needed for login)
- Visit /protectlock.cmd?password=X&sessionKey=Y (needed for login)
- Visit /Security_MacAddressFilter_Add.html (the data i need)
- Visit /index_lock.html (needed for logout)

I do this every 60 seconds. I tried to only log in once, stay logged in and access only the 3rd page at an interval.

There is also a 2 second delay between each requests.

So the problem: after about 12 hours (it varies) the router stops working. It shows a pink 404 page from micro_httpd (a tiny rudamentary web server). A router reset (pulling the plug) solves it for another 12 hours+-.

I'm guessing 4 requests per minute is too much for the micro_httpd webserver. But actually, it should be able to handle it.

The router is a "o2 HomeBox 6641", inside is Zyxel Router Technology.

Things i already did:
- tried to stay logged in and access only the data in need (dind't work)
- added the 2 second delay between each requests inside the sequence.

So I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Marius

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be a limit on the total number of requests before it stops working. It probably has a memory leak in the firmware, and stops working after memory is all used up.